# Can't see chatter feed tab in salesforce1

Tags: salesforce1-app, chatter

We have multiple users who can see chatter when they are in regular salesforce but they do not see the chatter feed when in salesforce1 and thus can use chatter.

The feeds tab appears on the right side in Salesforce1 Navigation. That isn't the issue.

What need to be done?

Comment: Is chatter tab added in Mobile Navigations ?

Comment: I only see salesforce1 navigation and feeds appear there not a chatter tab.

Comment: Yes .So feed tabs does not display feed?

Comment: correct as per my question.

Comment: Is it because you have different filters?

Comment: Filter on what? Can you explain?

Comment: So you have filters like my feed ,All feeds,etc . I am hoping it's something to do with that?

Comment: Where does one set such filters? I do not know where to look?

Comment: make sure you have enabled feed tracking for the Entites.